# Proper Vertx database etiquette

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm fairly new to Vertx, And trying to find some realistic examples of database usage.

I have a Verticle that creates a shared database object (And a number of classes that handle routing, but I would like to use the shared database outside the main class, obviously I could pass the database object in other classes constructors, but I'm sure Vertx has some better way to do this.

```
public void start() {
    ...
    this.postgreSQLClient = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, sqlClientConfig);
    ...
}
```

Does anyone have any Java Vertx examples with realistic implementations of a database?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [specify a pool name](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/java/#_specifying_a_pool_name):

> if different clients are created using the same Vert.x instance and
>   specifying the same pool name, they will share the same data source.

So updating your example:

```
public void start() {
  this.postgreSQLClient = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, sqlClientConfig, "my-shared-client");
}
```

Note that when doing this, the configuration provided in the first call will be used. Subsequent calls will simply return the existing client.

Comment: So run createShared from where ever I need it?

Comment: @AlexHaslam exactly (using the same name though!)

Comment: Thank you very much! Feels a bit weird... but it works!

Answer (score 3):

Use Dependency Injection. I have used [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice)
Here's the example of it:

Main.java

```
//within main function where you have object of vertx
Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector(vertx));
```

AppInjector.java

```
//Create an Injector file and bind your injections
PostgreSQLClient postgreSQLClient = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, sqlClientConfig, "my-shared-client");
bind(PostgreSQLClient.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("DBClient")).toInstance(postgreSQLClient);
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    @Named("DBClient")
    private PostgreSQLClient client;

}
```

You can find the source code [here](http://nirajmchauhan.tumblr.com/post/155841361091/java-vertx-mongo-client-guice)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also a good method, but I'll got with the default Vertx method as Highlighted by @tsegismont

I'll keep this in mind and upvote.